# Selecting full records, but only 1 of many (if multiple exist)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Say I have a table:

```
ID  | Store | Distance
111 | ABC | 0.0249126539935
111 | ABC | 0.0249126539935
111 | DEF | 0.0149126539935
111 | DEF | 0.0149126539935
```

I am attempting to return:

```
ID | Store | Distance
111 | ABC | 0.0249126539935
111 | DEF | 0.0149126539935
```

So far I have tried a few combinations of

```
SELECT DISTINCT InternalMemberID, Store, Distance, COUNT(*) count
FROM [RR Nearest 2 Stores]
GROUP BY InternalMemberID, Store, Distance
Having COUNT(*) = 1
```

But I seem to be generating vastly more rows than expected

Comment: What does your Distance column values look like in the table? Need to see an example please

Comment: I have updated my answer, remove the HAVING clause so you can return all unique records plus the multiple records grouped as 1 record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your example, it looks like you only want to return ID|Store but you are including the Distance column.

Try doing the following and removing the GROUP BY Distance column, this might return what you are looking for as the Distance column might contain different values for each record which would be returning more records than expected and throwing off your Group By clause.

```
SELECT InternalMemberID, Store, Distance, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM [RR Nearest 2 Stores]
GROUP BY InternalMemberID, Store, Distance
```

This query will return all records and group any multiple records like you asked for.

Comment: it's very close, but it seems to be de-duping also by the ID. So if an ID is in twice, it only shows a single record...

Comment: What exactly do you want to return as the end result then? from my understanding you wanted to return all records plus 1 record if multiple records are the same value in the `ID|Store|Distance` column

Comment: ah so I'll explain what has happened and that will clear it up I believe - someone accidentally duplicated our table into itself...so now we have for example ID1111 | Store123 | Distance123 twice for Zac, instead of once. At the same time, we have ID1111 | Store222 | Distance 234 twice also for Zac. So Zac has ID 1111 and appears in 4 different rows. But each row has been duplicated one time, so we need to return it so that Zac (1111) has only 2 rows, and the duplicate rows are gone but currently, Zac is only appearing in a single row, rather than 2

Comment: Yeah okay so my query will actually fix that problem, so the fact you are not getting your 2 records like you mentioned must be something else, the query I have written above will group any records where ID, Store and Distance are the exact same value but all 3 have to match, It can NOT group Only by ID unless you only specify ID in your SELECT and GROUP BY.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!